# why isn't the socket connection counter updating?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

this is the code I have in an index.html (client). Im wondering why the number is not being incremented. I expect on each time a socket connect I give it a unique name.

```
 var number = 0;

    socket.on("connect",function(){
         number = number+1;

        socket.emit("add user","user"+ number )


    })
```

but when i have this server

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){

    console.log("io.onconnection")
    socket.on("add user", function(data){ 
    console.log(data)
    })
});
```

on each connection i get logged `user1`, **why** isn't the second connection `user2`? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because javascript is a client side, and number will always be 0 every time the page refresh/load.

You can count the number client connected in your websocket,  server then pass it to js and then you can increment.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It was helpful. but i was trying to figure out which client performed action and i thought i could do that from the client side.. can you also answer this question that pertains to my problem please . 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31911606/how-can-you-tell-which-socket-connection-clicked-a-button-using-socket-io